# Modifying requests using Burpsuite considered to be valid security vulnerability?

Tags: security, web-applications, burp

I would like to know if intercepting and modifying requests using Burpsuite before reaching server is considered as vulnerability.

In our web based and mobile applications, adequate security measures are in place to avoid replay attack and data integrity etc.,

Now the same is being evaluated by one of the application security teams, they use burpsuite to intercept the request payload and have raised few security vulnerabilities which aren't reproducible without using Burpsuite.

So using such tools is still a valid case and considered to be vulnerable?

Comment: This question would be a better fit on security.stackexchange.com Most vulnerabilities are valid even if they need Burp or other security tools to exploit. However, some are not. For example a cross-site scripting attack relied on the victim running Burp and performing a particular modification - that would not normally be recognized as a valid security issue.

Comment: Every Web/API request needs to be Client & Server Side validated against Negative Test Data.

i.e. If you've initiating a payment are able to intercept & modify the request payload with desired "amount" to a "less" value but able to purchase the product by paying less, then your server should handle the modified "amount" gracefully.

Comment: Let me explain test case which i am trying to find a solution, to avoid replay attack i use client and server nonce in my web application. Requests are intercepted using burp-suite and only the client nonce is changed and forwarded to the server and its obvious request will be processed. It is raised to be a vulnerability.

Comment: @Samy - If this was raised by a penetration testing company, have the conversation with them. Most applications do not need explicit protection against replay attacks and can rely on the defences built into SSL. However, most applications do need a token to protect against CSRF attacks which may be what you're referring to.

Comment: @PortSwigger Yes you are right, it is raised as an issue by one of the VAPT companies. CRSF Token is already in place. Tried explaining that we should leverage on SSL for this and they are reluctant to buy that argument.